# git push command in a custom script - how to do it quietly?

Tags: ruby, git, bash

In a Ruby script, I have a set of git commands. I would like to prevent the output of the `git push` from being displayed in the console (no output or written in amp file)

```
git push origin master
   Counting objects: 440, done.
   Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
   Comprssing objects: 100% (405/405), done.
   Writing objects: 100% (440/440), 353.50 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
   Total 440 (delta 115), reused 0 (delta 0)
   To git@bitbucket.org:myname/mygitrepo.git
   + 184a611...a52775d master -> master
```

As I am using steps in my script, this output is inserted in the current step report flow ... messing it. What should I do to suppress that output?

UPDATE

I am running a commands set, I am interested to detect ONLY success or failure of the whole set ...

```
%x[ 
cd "#{@project_path}"
git init 2> /dev/null
cp "#{@dockerfile_template}" "#{@project_path}"
git add --all 2> /dev/null
git commit -m "first commit" 2> /dev/null
git remote add origin "#{@project_repository}" 2> /dev/null
git push -u origin master 2> /dev/null
]

if $?.success?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also combine stdout and stderr to /dev/null

```
git push origin master > /dev/null 2>&1
```

But be aware that if error comes out, you won't be able to see it.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion ... I'm not interested by the details of any error in the commands set, onlt to know if there was any error running the set , ( see the updated question .. does it will get it ?

Comment: I never programmed in ruby, but `$?` will save the result of a previous command, then just test it. If it is not equal to zero it means some kind of an error occured...hope this helps

Comment: thanks that what I doing now ... will test later all kind of errors

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want the script to run git push quietly only in case of success? Then you can try this

```
Dir.chdir "/path/to/repo" do
  output=`git push origin master 2>&1`
  ret=$?.exitstatus
  if (ret != 0) then
    puts output
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try redirecting to /dev/null.  ie, use the command:

```
    git push origin master > /dev/null
```

Or possibly (if get outputs to stderr):

```
    git push origin master 2> /dev/null
```